# How can I correctly calculate a percentage of a number

Tags: percentages, ratio

I'm sending a transfer from the Stripe payout service API.
I'd like to calculate out the Stripe payout fees ($0.25$%) from each transfer to a bank account?

**Problem** - I need to collect/recoup fees from each transfer to cover my fees ($5$%) plus the Stripe Connect fees ($0.25$%) and I'm unsure about how to compute the numbers as taking $0.25$% of the transfer will equate to a larger % than what Stripe will take in the payout.

FYI - Stripe takes their $0.25$% from the payout when sent to the bank account.

Ex. Transfer 10 dollars to bank account minus Stripe fees and my fees

$10$ dollars - $5$% (my fee) $\rightarrow$ $9.50$ dollars

Next I take out $0.25$% (stripe fee) of $9.50 = 9.50 - 0.2375c = 9.2625$

I now send(transfer) $9.2625$ to the bank account

Now when Stripe pays out it will take $0.25$% of $9.2625 = 0.2316c

So the problem is I'm taking $0.25$% out of $9.50$ and Stripe is taking $0.25$% out of $9.2625$.

Can anyone help correct this math?

Comment: Wherever you say 0.25% you presumably mean $2.5\%$, is that correct? Also, what do you want to be equal? The Stripe fee you collect after you've collected your fee (which is now (probably incorrectly) 2.5% of 9.50) and the Stripe fee they collect (which is 2.5% of what's been transferred)? Is that correct?

Comment: no it's 0.25% https://stripe.com/connect/pricing When I say I want it to be equal, what I'm trying to say is Stripe will take 0.25% from what has been transferred. So if I transfer 10.00, Stripe will debit $0.25 cents from my account. I want to calculate what that debited amount is, so that I can remove it from the transferred amount first and have it in my account, so that when Stripe debits it from my account it equates to 0.

Comment: Ah, you did all your calculations with $2.5\%$ - note that $0.25\%$ of $9.50$ is $0.\color{red}{0}2375$.

Comment: It's been 20+ years since school, but isn't 0.25% equal to 1/4 of 1 percent? I'm reading that correctly right? So isn't 0.25% of $10.00 => 25 cents? So 0.25% of 9.50 would be just a little under 25 cents =? ~2375 cents?

Comment: It would be like that if you started with $\$100.00$. Then $1\%$ is $\$1.00$ and $0.25\%$ is $25$ cents. But here you start with $10$ times smaller amount.

Comment: Sorry about the mix up. The initial price isn't important 10, 100, 1000. Getting the 0.25% out of it to match the Stripe fee is what I need to calculate

Comment: Not a problem, it is just when I read the question it was a bit confusing. All clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $A$ money after deducing your own fee, and you want to deduce $x\%$ so that this is equal to $z\%$ deduction that Stripe does? In this case:

- Your Stripe deduction: $A\frac{x}{100}$
- Money sent: $A(1-\frac{x}{100})$
- Stripe deduces: $A\left(1-\frac{x}{100}\right)\frac{z}{100}$

and you want:

$$A\frac{x}{100}=A\left(1-\frac{x}{100}\right)\frac{z}{100}$$

i.e. (cancelling $A$ and solving for $x$):

$$x=\frac{z}{1+\frac{z}{100}}$$

In our case, $z=0.25$ which means $x=\frac{1000}{401}\approx 0.249377$ to six significant digits. In other words, you would deduce $0.249377\%$.

For $10.00$, this means:

- You would deduce your fee $5\%=0.50$. ($9.50$ remaining.)
- You would deduce Stripe fee $9.50\cdot 0.249377\%=0.02369$. ($9.47631$ remaining.)
- Stripe will transfer that and charge you $9.47631\cdot 0.25\%=0.02369$ - same as previous!

Comment: Thanks for the nice equations! If I also wanted to remove Stripes $.25 cent flat fee as well, would I just subtract that from the first amount as well?

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. So you won't start from $9.50$ but from $9.50-0.0025=9.4975$ but everything else (including the percentage you use to offset Stripe fee) stays the same.

Comment: I forgot to add that this answer *does not constitute a financial advice* and I am not to be held responsible for any loss you may suffer due to its incorrectness or inapplicability to your particular situation.

Comment: I think so, see Stripe also charges me a flat rate of $0.25 cents per payout and $2.00 per payout per month. So I'd like to figure out how to remove the 2 flat rates (.25cents and 2.00) from one of the transfers each month.

Comment: For the flat rate per transaction, it is as above. For the $2,00$ ($2$ dollars or $2$ cents?) I don't know. It is down to you how to sort it out. If Stripe only sees you as a customer, and you have multiple customers, it would be unfair to charge a random customer who just happens to be your first customer in the month! You may want to waive it altogether and pay it out of your $5\%$ fee. Or estimate how many transfers you have in a month and spread it, etc. This is your policy decision, really.